# Java Swing GUI is freezing if the values of several textfields are saved on a textfile using Scanner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I made a Java Swing GUI ATMSystem and I came across a problem on saving the textfields on a textfile(*named ACCOUNT NUMBERS.txt*) that saves ACCOUNT,PIN, SAVINGS BALANCE, CHECKING BALANCE, and CREDIT CARD BALANCE for deposit and withdrawal.

while running the program...

after pressing "REGISTER" button, The whole GUI **FREEZES**, i used scanner since it can read separate entries per line on the textfile to compare it soon to Login on the ATM and use the Savings, Checking, and Credit Card balance from the textfile that the program is going to read but I am stuck on the REGISTER part because of GUI freeze. Are there any tips?

```
JButton Register_button = new JButton("REGISTER");
Register_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File file=new File("ACCOUNT NUMBERS.txt");
        Scanner ACCOUNT = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{  
            String AN = AN_passfield.getText();
            String PIN = PIN_passfield.getText();
            int SAB = Integer.parseInt(SAB_textfield.getText());
            int CAB = Integer.parseInt(CAB_textfield.getText());
            int CCAB = Integer.parseInt(CCAB_textfield.getText());

            String  ANs = ACCOUNT.next(AN);
            String  PINs = ACCOUNT.next(PIN);
            int  SABs = ACCOUNT.nextInt(SAB);
            int CABs = ACCOUNT.nextInt(CAB);
            int  CCABs = ACCOUNT.nextInt(CCAB);

            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
        
            pw.write(ANs+" "+PINs+" "+SABs+" "+CABs+" "+CCABs+"\n");
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            ACCOUNT.close();
            ATMSignUPSuccess.main(new String[] {});
            frame.dispose();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It freezes because your program is awaiting your input in the console. You created a `Scanner` hooked to `System.in`, and then call `next`. I think you meant to create the scanner like this: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);`

Comment: Long running tasks should also not be performed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You should read the section on [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) from the swing tutorial.

Comment: The real question here is why use a Scanner that reads console input? I mean whats the point of a GUI if u are using console?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. since i thought it can read separate entries per line on the textfile to compare it soon to Login on the ATM and use the Savings, Checking, and Credit Card balance from the textfile that the program is going to read

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with upper case characters.  *to compare it soon to Login* - Don't use a Scanner with a GUI. Create a JDialog with userid and password components.